# Save a large JSON to Realm using Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, realm

I have a JSON with more or less 75 keys.

I need to receive this JSON and store offline it using Realm.

I do not want to iterate through the keys, since I've heard that there are ways to save a large JSON using a few lines. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**
My JSON (
I saved on a server away because it's too big)
http://myjson.com/i7e6l

Comment: Asking for third party libs is off topic. I have removed that part from your question. Moreover, it will help if you were to add a JSON sample and your existing code for saving it.

Comment: I edited my question with the link to my JSON. I did not put any examples of how I am saving because I have nothing yet.

Comment: So you want to persist the JSON as it is in Realm, without actually parsing it?

Comment: I am new to this offline storage tool. As far as I know, if I parse this JSON will spend many rows and demand a lot of time. So I wanted some alternative.
But if there is any way I can parse more easily, I will accept it too!

Comment: @RodrigoFuscaldi Check my answer, but in short, there is no short way to parse a JSON response, once you have to put in the work to turn a `JSON` response into `Swift` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy, one liner to parse the JSON and store it in `Realm`, since each `JSON` response is unique and no framework can have explicit knowledge about the structure of your `JSON` response without you giving some information to this framework about your `JSON`.

You will need to write some code either to parse the response or to make a mapping between your `JSON` response's fields and the properties of your `Realm` object. If you choose the latter solution, you can use [Alamofire Object Mapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) to do the `JSON` parsing automatically, but even then you have to write code for the mapping.

Comment: Thanks, buddy.
I'll do it all by myself, even though it takes longer.

Comment: No worries. Once you get the hang of `JSON` parsing, it will go really fast, believe me. And you only have to do it once per API response.